# できたら Mother's Day Grammar Breakdown

Tags: grammar

I was reading an article in the "Easy Japanese" app about Mother's day flowers and stumbled upon this sentence:

農家【のうか】の小河原一雄【こがわらかずお】さんは「お母【かあ】さんに『ありがとう』の気持【きも】ちを伝える【つたえる】お手伝い【おてつだい】ができたらいいなと思います【おもいます】」と言っています【いっています】。

I'm struggling to understand the meaning/nuance of the sentence, besides something along the lines of "Farmer Kogawarakazuo said, 'I think it's good if I helped to convey thankful feelings to mothers.'"

Could you please explain the meaning of the sentence, especially the "～できたらいいなと思います" part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 農家{のうか}​の​小河原一雄{こがわらかずお}さん​は「お​母{かあ}​さんに『ありがとう』の​気持
>   {きも}​ちを​伝{つた}​えるお​手伝{てつだ}​いができたらいいなと​思{おも}​います」と​言{い}​っています。

～～できたらいいな**と**思います ＝ 「～～できたらいいな」**と**思います

Thus, the 「と」 is quotative.  Kogawara is quoting his own thought/idea/feeling/hope here. "***I think it would be great if I could ~~***"

This sentence is actually quite complex (for being called Easy Japanese) in terms of expressing who does what.  Here is a list of **actions and their performers**.

お母さんに『ありがとう』の気持ちを伝える ("to convey their gratitude to their mothers") ⇒ **people**

お手伝いができたらいいなと思います (to think it would be great to be of help [to those people mentioned above]) ⇒ **Kogawara**

言っています (to be saying) ⇒ **Kogawara**

As usual, the performers are generally unmentioned.  In this case, the only one explicitly mentioned (out of the three) is Kogarawa for the action of 「言っています」.

> Kazuo Kogawara, the farmer, says "It would be great if I could help people convey their feelings of thankfulness to their mothers."